# Can you use line-of-sight abilities (such as shadow jaunt) if you have blind sight to a location?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, line-of-sight, line-of-effect

Scenario is: your character is blind, but has blind sight. Can this character use blind sight to shadow jaunt to a location within his range of sight (LOS) (usually 60 ft) or does this not apply?

Does having blind sight affect Line of Effect (LOE)? (Would the character know they can't reach someplace with the teleport that they can see with blind sight?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use shadow jaunt in this case.

If your character has blind sight, the blindness, is not important.
Mechanically talking, if you have blind sight you can "see" everything from people to walls.(even invisible characters/objects).

You can even see trough darkness, fog, water etc etc.
The only things that stops your ability to "see", with blind sight, are walls/ceilings and nearly everything that blocks line of effect.

> Blindsight (Ex)
>
> Using nonvisual senses, such as sensitivity to vibrations, keen smell, acute hearing, or echolocation, a creature with blindsight maneuvers and fights as well as a sighted creature. Invisibility, darkness, and most kinds of concealment are irrelevant, though the creature must have line of effect to a creature or object to discern that creature or object. [...]
>
> Blindsight never allows a creature to distinguish color or visual contrast. A creature cannot read with blindsight.
>
> Blindsight does not subject a creature to gaze attacks (even though darkvision does).
>
> Blinding attacks do not penalize creatures using blindsight.
>
> Deafening attacks thwart blindsight if it relies on hearing.
>
> Blindsight works underwater but not in a vacuum.
>
> Blindsight negates displacement and blur effects.